# Term for set of all possible $n \times n$ zero-one matrices for a given $n$?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, terminology

Is there a term in mathematics for the **SET** of all possible $n \times n$ zero-one matrices?

In other words, for a particular $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, is there a term for the set of all possible $M=[m_{ij}]$ such that either $m_{ij}=0$ or $m_{ij}=1$ for $1\le i \le n$ and $1\le j \le n$?

$\{ M=[m_{ij}] : m_{ij}=1 \vee m_{ij}=0, 1\le i \le n, 1\le j \le n\}$

Thank you.

Comment: Uh, just trying to guess what you mean: do you mean that $|S|=n$ and you are representing a relation on $S$ by putting a $1$ in the $i,j$ position if $(i,j)$ is in your relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the set ${\Bbb B}^{n \times n}$ of $n \times n$ Boolean matrices. You can extend the notation to ${\Bbb B}^{n \times m}$, the set of $n \times m$-matrices with entries in the Boolean semiring.

Comment: Wouldn't $\mathbb{B}^{n^2}$ be set of all possible $n^2$-tuples populated with $1$s and $0$s? This is not exactly a set of matrices.

Comment: Isn't $n \times n = n^2$?

Comment: of course it is, but i am not questioning whether $n \cdot n = n^2$. Your definition produces a set of tuples and not a set of matrices. That is what I am questioning

Comment: I don't understand your comment: $k^{n \times n}$ is a standard notation for the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $k$.

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant $\mathbb{B} = \{ 0,1 \}$ and $\mathbb{B}^{n^2}  = \{0,1\}_1 \times \{0,1\}_2 \times ... \times \{0,1\}_{n^2}$

Comment: I indeed mean ${\Bbb B} = \{0, 1\}$, the Boolean semiring. Just replace $k$ by $\Bbb B$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a matrix an [**adjacency matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) since basically that would be choosing to represent the relation as a graph with vertices in $S$. (This was more relevant before [the OP removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3676127/1) the original context.)

These are sometimes collectively called (even with dimensions $m,n$) [**binary matrices**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/01-Matrix.html).

There is a slight conundrum with what the entries actually are. You might or might not operate with binary arithmetic or binary operations on the entries. For an adjacency matrix, you often want the entries to be positive integers with their operations.  This allows you to compute $n$-th order adjacency in a graph.

But in your case, you're looking for simply a true/false that an element is in the relation: then maybe it is reasonable to think of them as elements in the field of two elements.  I'm not sure what algebraic interpretation could be attached to operations with these matrices, though.

Comment: I am not asking what the term is for a matrix that represents a relation $R$ on $S$. These are often called connection matrices. I want to the know if there is a term for the SET of all possible connection matrices (representing all possible relations on $S$).

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Yeah.. I wrote one... binary matrices. I figured both the term for the singular and the collective set would be useful.

Comment: I edited my question above. hopefully it is more clear without talk of relations

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I don't see why that was necessary or how it changes anything, but OK.  It is actually bad form to edit your question in such a way that existing answers apply to the old but not the new.